# Rotation about Camera

Tags: opengl, matrix, camera, rotation

In OpenGL, if you rotate first and translate afterwards, then all objects will rotate about their own origins. If you translate first and then rotate, objects should rotate around the origin (camera). But this doesn't happen. Everything rotates about the world axis, not the camera.
This:

```
    transformationMatrix.setIdentity();

    transformationMatrix.mul(rotationMatrixX);
    transformationMatrix.mul(rotationMatrixZ);
    transformationMatrix.mul(rotationMatrixY);

    transformationMatrix.mul(translationMatrix);
```

doesn't work. How do I rotate everything around the camera? For object in the center of the "world" (a cube at 0,0,0), translation and rotation are relative to the camera. The code above rotates the whole world, but the center of the world never changes its coordinates relative to camera. The camera has always the same direction of view.

===========================================

ADDED:

THERE IS NO lwjgl.util IN lwjgl 3 ANYMORE. SO NO gluLookAt FUNCTION.

I'v solved the problem by rotation around arbitrary axis. Tries to use JOGL, but somethig is wrong: [JOGL setPerspective wrong?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33398712/jogl-setperspective-wrong)

Comment: I have fixed you question's language. Please verify that the content is as you intended. Please also include where your camera is coming from. Do you have another matrix for the camera? So you basically want to rotate the camera (and leave the world unchanged)?

Comment: gluLookAt(GLdouble eyeX,GLdouble eyeY,GLdouble eyeZ,GLdouble centerX,GLdouble centerY,GLdouble centerZ,GLdouble upX,GLdouble upY,GLdouble upZ); sets your camera parameters